# how many ways we can get the value of current session id in php

Tags: php, session

how many different ways can we get the value of current session id in php?

Comment: What’s the purpose of this question? Shouldn’t it be: What’s the best way to get the current session ID?

Answer (score 1):

We can get the value of current session with the use of `session_id()` returns the session id for the current session.

Apart from session_id, we can retrieve it using `SID` constant in PHP6.

Also look at : [PHP-sessions](http://www.careerride.com/PHP-sessions.aspx)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually, the `SID` constant has been around for quite some time.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the php manual for [session id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php). There are links to related functions as well :)

Answer (score 0):

To see all available SESSION I use the following code:

```
foreach($_SESSION as $k=>$v)
   echo "$k=>$v<br/>";
```

Above code will be helpful when you are working with lots of SESSION variables.